# Save file while keeping the same formatting in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a program which gives me stock info when I give it an input file.

This file iterates every row and does some simple calculations.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    ticker=row['Ticker']

    ticker_stock = yf.Ticker(ticker.strip())
    data = ticker_stock.history()
    row['Price'] = (data.tail(1)['Close'].iloc[0])

    #Print Stock Name
    stockName = ticker_stock.info['longName']
    print(stockName)

    print(row['Ticker'], row['Price'])

    row['Value'] = row['BuyPrice'] * row['BuyAmount']
    print(row['Value'])

    row.to_csv('balance.csv')
```

I want to save the file after doing the calculations, but the format is different.

Here is an example of the input file:

```
0,Ticker,BuyPrice,BuyAmount,Value,Price
1,MSFT,4832,4,43,456
```

And here is the output file created by the program.

```
,2
Ticker,MSFT
BuyPrice,4832.0
BuyAmount,4
Value,19328.0
Price,215.80999755859375
```

Is there a way to save the file while keeping the original format? It is clear that if I want to rerun the program it will not work. Since the rows are now columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the corrected code:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    ticker=row['Ticker']

    ticker_stock = yf.Ticker(ticker.strip())
    data = ticker_stock.history()
    df.loc[index, 'Price'] = (data.tail(1)['Close'].iloc[0])

    #Print Stock Name
    stockName = ticker_stock.info['longName']
    print(stockName)

    print(df.loc[index, 'Ticker'], df.loc[index, 'Price'])

    df.loc[index, 'Value'] = row['BuyPrice'] * row['BuyAmount']
    print(df.loc[index, 'Value'])

df.to_csv('balance.csv')
```

Changes:

1. take the to_csv outside the loop
2. you to_csv just once and the DF
3. updating value using df.loc[index, ]

Comment: This works for keeping the right formatting, but doesn't save the correct data. In fact, the file doesn't seem to save anything. For example, the price which I get in the loop is not saved. I think it is because the ```row['Price']``` is calculated but not the ```df['Price']```